# How to Customize CAS login and validation

Tags: authentication, cas

I'm implementing `CAS` in my web application.

Can someone explain how to avoid `CAS` login and replace it with my application login?

The second question is - where the `CAS` login details are validated?

Comment: There is a full explanation of your qustion [Using CAS without the CAS login screen](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+CAS+login+screen). And it is official souce. Take a look also at [Using CAS without the Login Screen](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+Login+Screen). The names of the links are almost the same, but they content a different information.